# What is a good practice to realize complex REST calls?

Tags: javascript, rest, http, https

I am currently programming a REST API using Node.js that calculates the beeline between two geographical coordinates. In order to calculate the result i need following 4 parameters:

- `start_lon`
- `start_lat`
- `end_lon`
- `end_lat`

So, should my call look line this:

`http://hostname/beeline/{start_lon}/{start_lat}/{end_lon}/{end_lat}`

or more like this:

`http://hostname/beeline?start_lon={start_lon}&start_lat={start_lat}&end_lon={end_lon}&end_lat={end_lat}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you have 4 *parameters* to calculate the beeline. Then you would use HTTP query parameters against the beeline resource. Then:

```
http://hostname/beeline?start_lon={start_lon}&start_lat={start_lat}&end_lon={end_lon}&end_lat={end_lat}
```

This way, parameters *variabilize* the way to access to the beeline resource.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the latter, because there is no hierarchical relationship between the parameters (in contrast for example to /images/123 where the image number 123 is "under", in a hierarchical sense, the "images" folder)